# how to get the inside id using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to assign values to inside id how can i do that in Jquery

controller.cs code

```
public GroupModel Get()
        {
            IGroupTypeRepository groupTypeRepo = new GroupTypeRepository();
            IGroupRepository groupRepo = new GroupRepository();
            var model = new GroupModel();            
                model.GroupTypes = groupTypeRepo.GetAll().ToList();
                Guid first = model.GroupTypes.FirstOrDefault().Id;
                model.Groups = groupRepo.GetAll().Where(s => s.Type == first).ToList();

            return model;
        }
```

I tried like following

```
function getGroups() {
            debugger;
            $.getJSON(
                "groupvalues",
    function (data) {
        if (data.GroupTypes != undefined) {
            $.each(data.Groups, function (jindex, jvalue) {
                debugger;
                if (jvalue.Id != undefined) {
                    $("#GroupsTemplate").tmpl(jvalue).appendTo(".span9 .row #projects");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    <div class="span9">
        <div class="row">
            <section id="projects">

            </section>                    
        </div>
    </div>

    <script id="GroupsTemplate" type="text/html">
        <ul id="thumbs">
            <li class="item-thumbs span3 Dhol">
                <span class="font-icon-music"></span>${GroupType.TypeName}<br />
                </p></div> </li>
        </ul>                        
    </script>
```

I guess i'm going wrong here in js function

> $("#GroupsTemplate").tmpl(jvalue).appendTo(".span9 .row #projects");

Comment: What does `jvalue` or `data.Groups` contain?

Comment: It contains the model values from controller

Comment: what happens when you run this ? what is wrong ?

Comment: I'm unable to bind data on html 
Could not able to see values of Group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that instead of this:

```
${GroupType.TypeName}
```

you must have only this:

```
${TypeName}
```

because the GroupType is the parameter object for the template (implicit).

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: okies thanks one thing that i wonder i'm binding correct as by `id=project` is `inside .span9`

Comment: no luck :( 
foreach having value only for 1st element after that it failed and on html it is not showing anything

Comment: I need you to do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(jvalue))` and paste here the result please